# Уникальные значения в двух селлектах

Tags: angularjs

вопрос по первому Angular. У меня есть 2 селлекта:

```js
 <div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>Tag:<i class="is-required" ng-if="vm.isEditing">*</i></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control" ng-class="{'ng-touched' : vm.savePressed}" ng-model="vm.availableExtraRules[$index].tagId" ng-disabled="!vm.isEditing"
                ng-options="tag.tagId as tag.tagName for tag in vm.TS.data.availableTags" required>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label>Exclude tag:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control" ng-class="{'ng-touched' : vm.savePressed}" ng-model="vm.trigger.options.extraRules[$index].excludeTagId"
                ng-disabled="!vm.isEditing" ng-options="tag.tagId as tag.tagName for tag in vm.TS.data.availableTags">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Список для селлекта берется из одного источника.
Как можно сделать чтоб когда выбираешь значение в первом селлекте, то во втором нельзя было выбрать этоже значение и наоборот...

Comment: Что означает *нельзя было выбрать*? Выключить option? Спрятать? Не давать его выбирать?

Comment: Любое из перечисленного.

Comment: Для любого из них будет будет свой подход и свой код.

Answer (score 0):

Предагаю сделать источником для списков функцию или метод, где будет происходить необходимая фильтрация списков.

```js
function doubleSelectorController($scope) {
  this.options = [
    'apple',
    'orange',
    'lemon'
  ];
  
  this.getOptions = (propName) => {
     const excludedProp = (propName === 'first')
      ? $scope['second']
      : $scope['first'];
      const output = this.options.filter(item => item !== excludedProp);
      return output;
  };
}
const doubleSelector = {
    template: `
    <form class="pure-form">
        <select 
          ng-model="first"
          ng-options="item for item in $ctrl.getOptions('first')"
        >
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>

        <select 
          ng-model="second"
          ng-options="item for item in $ctrl.getOptions('second')"
        >
           <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    `,
    controller: doubleSelectorController
}

doubleSelectorController.$inject = ['$scope'];

angular.module('app', [])
.component('doubleSelector', doubleSelector);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('root'), ['app']);
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.1/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-oAOxQR6DkCoMliIh8yFnu25d7Eq/PHS21PClpwjOTeU2jRSq11vu66rf90/cZr47" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <double-selector></double-selector>
</div>
```